# VBA To Open Links in TOR (each in a new tab)

Tags: excel, vba, firefox, tor

Can you please advise how do I open a selection of links (each in a separate tab) in TOR (Firefox)?

My code works with e.g. one instance (one link from one cell in Excel) and it opens it in TOR but if I select more than one cell then it opens one and then tries to open a new instance of TOR to open another (and I cannot have two opened at once).

```
Sub Open_Tor()
'open hyperlink in tor
Dim tor As String
'tor = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
tor = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe"
Dim hl As Hyperlink
On Error Resume Next
For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
Shell (tor & " -url-newtab " & hl.Address)
Next hl
End Sub
```

If you do not have TOR you can simply change the path to your Chrome to test it (and Chrome will nicely open one link after the other, each in a separate Tab).

Thanks

PS. I cannot work with Chrome due to a daily limit of calculations I can perform on a specific server, hence the use of TOR (which changes IPs constantly).

Comment: Try the VPN service (e.g. Protonmail offers it free of charge) and continue using Chrome if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Wheeliam , it is somewhat "a solution", although I would rather use Chrome if possible. If no one will be able to help I will resort to your suggestion. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following two codes (paste in two separate modules). Add a button on one of the sheets (to trigger the code) if you want and direct it to the EventMacro code. Remember to adjust the `alertTime` and `Application.Wait` values to the speed/specs of your machine.

```
Sub EventMacro()
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:08")
OpenInAnotherBrowser Sheet2.Cells(2, 2).Value 'provide a link in this location on a specific sheet (in my case Sheet2)
Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
End Sub
```

Now, thanks to this code, you will get a loop of open/close Tor browser with a specific link located in `Sheet2.Cells(2, 2)`! :D

```
Sub OpenInAnotherBrowser(url As String)
    Dim firefoxPath As String
    Dim wshell As Object
    Dim oExec As Object
    Set wshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   
    firefoxPath = "C:\Users\T14s\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe" 'provide path to Tor folder where firefox.exe is based
   
    If Dir(firefoxPath) = "" Then pathFireFox = "C:\Users\T14s\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe" 'provide path to Tor folder where firefox.exe is based

    Set oExec = wshell.Exec(firefoxPath & " " & url)

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) 'adjust based on your machine's specs
   
    oExec.Terminate
    Set wshell = Nothing
    Set oExec = Nothing

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'adjust based on your machine's specs
    Application.SendKeys "^+Q" 'quit Tor

End Sub
```